# Given a continuous $f:[a,b]\to\Bbb R,$ how to show its zero set has a minimum if non-empty?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f : [a, b] → \Bbb R$ be continuous, and suppose that $Z = \{x ∈ [a, b] : f(x) = 0\}$ is nonempty. Prove that $Z$ has a smallest element.

I know by theorem that every nonempty subset of $\Bbb Z$ which is bounded above has a maximum and by corollary, every nonempty subset of $\Bbb Z$ which is bounded below has a minimum. How do I use the well-ordering principle here?

Comment: I have formatted your post. Please notice the difference between $Z$ and $\Bbb Z.$ One is the set of all integers. The other is the set of all zeroes of the function $f.$ These are *not* the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

Since $\;Z\subset [a,b]\;$ is bounded it has an infimum, say $\;\omega\;$ . This means that for any $\;n\in\Bbb N\;$ there exists $\;z_n\in Z\;$ s.t.

$$\omega\le z_n<\omega+\frac1n\stackrel{\text{apply squeeze th.}}\implies z_n\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}\omega$$

Using continuity we get

$$0=\lim_{n\to\infty}f(z_n)=f(\omega)\implies \omega\in Z\;,\;\;\text{and we're done}$$

Comment: Simple and elegant. +1 The same argument applies for the maximum element of $Z$ also.

Answer (score 0):

You *can't* use the well-ordering principle, since you don't know that $Z$ is well-ordered, nor even necessarily well-orderable.

Rather, what you must show is that $\inf Z\in Z$--that is, the greatest lower bound of $Z$ (which exists because...?) is an element of $Z.$ Continuity is essential, here.

Answer (score 0):

In a continuous function, inverse image of a closed set is closed. ${0}$ is a closed set. So it's inverse, the zero set, is also closed and bounded. So it must have a Maximum and minimum.